# Issue with submit in Extjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1.3 . I am submitting the form with

```
 'standardSubmit: true'
```

In server side we use asp.net webapi. i create a excel in code and attach the same in my HTTPResponseMessage content. when  'standardSubmit: true' i am getting the file downloaded in the browser. When i use `'standardSubmit: false'` file is not getting downloaded even if it contains the proper content type and attachment.In this case i am getting the excel xml in the response.

The problem with  'standardSubmit: true' is that it is not showing success/failure (I cannot even see the response). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that file upload is handled very differently from other inputs due to AJAX limitation of not allowing file uploads.

The framework does not use ajax to submit the form as usual because of the file upload, see the docs on this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload

It uses hidden IFrame to submit and process returned data. Follow instructions carefully to set response header from the server to "text/html"